# borda no TR nao aparecendo

Tags: css, table

Estou a aplicar borda no TR das `<tables>` porém de forma alguma ele aparece, veja o trecho do código:

```
.rwd-table tr {
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

Vejam código completo:

```css
.rwd-table {
  margin: 1em 0;
  min-width: 300px;
}
.rwd-table tr {
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.rwd-table th {
  display: none;
}
.rwd-table td {
  display: block;
}
.rwd-table td:first-child {
  padding-top: .5em;
}
.rwd-table td:last-child {
  padding-bottom: .5em;
}
.rwd-table td:before {
  content: attr(data-th) ": ";
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 6.5em;
  display: inline-block;
}
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .rwd-table td:before {
    display: none;
  }
}
.rwd-table th, .rwd-table td {
  text-align: left;
}
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .rwd-table th, .rwd-table td {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: .25em .5em;
  }
  .rwd-table th:first-child, .rwd-table td:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  .rwd-table th:last-child, .rwd-table td:last-child {
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}

h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  color: #34495E;
}

.rwd-table {
  background: #34495E;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: .4em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.rwd-table tr {
  border-color: #46627f;
}
.rwd-table th, .rwd-table td {
  margin: .5em 1em;
}
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .rwd-table th, .rwd-table td {
    padding: 1em !important;
  }
}
.rwd-table th, .rwd-table td:before {
  color: #dd5;
}
```

```html
<style class="cp-pen-styles">@import "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,700";
.rwd-table {
  margin: 1em 0;
  min-width: 300px;
}
.rwd-table tr {
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.rwd-table th {
  display: none;
}
.rwd-table td {
  display: block;
}
.rwd-table td:first-child {
  padding-top: .5em;
}
.rwd-table td:last-child {
  padding-bottom: .5em;
}
.rwd-table td:before {
  content: attr(data-th) ": ";
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 6.5em;
  display: inline-block;
}
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .rwd-table td:before {
    display: none;
  }
}
.rwd-table th, .rwd-table td {
  text-align: left;
}
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .rwd-table th, .rwd-table td {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: .25em .5em;
  }
  .rwd-table th:first-child, .rwd-table td:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  .rwd-table th:last-child, .rwd-table td:last-child {
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}

h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  color: #34495E;
}

.rwd-table {
  background: #34495E;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: .4em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.rwd-table tr {
  border-color: #46627f;
}
.rwd-table th, .rwd-table td {
  margin: .5em 1em;
}
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .rwd-table th, .rwd-table td {
    padding: 1em !important;
  }
}
.rwd-table th, .rwd-table td:before {
  color: #dd5;
}
</style></head><body>
<h1>RWD List to Table</h1>
<table class="rwd-table">
  <tr>
    <th>Movie Title</th>
    <th>Genre</th>
    <th>Year</th>
    <th>Gross</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-th="Movie Title">Star Wars</td>
    <td data-th="Genre">Adventure, Sci-fi</td>
    <td data-th="Year">1977</td>
    <td data-th="Gross">$460,935,665</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-th="Movie Title">Howard The Duck</td>
    <td data-th="Genre">"Comedy"</td>
    <td data-th="Year">1986</td>
    <td data-th="Gross">$16,295,774</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-th="Movie Title">American Graffiti</td>
    <td data-th="Genre">Comedy, Drama</td>
    <td data-th="Year">1973</td>
    <td data-th="Gross">$115,000,000</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De acordo com a [sessão 17.6](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#borders) da recomendação:

> Rows, columns, row groups, and column groups cannot have borders
>   (i.e., user agents must ignore the border properties for those
>   elements).

[17.6.2 The collapsing border model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#collapsing-borders):

> In the collapsing border model, it is possible to specify borders that
>   surround all or part of a cell, row, row group, column, and column
>   group. Borders for HTML's "rules" attribute can be specified this way.

Para "corrigir" este problema basta adicionar a regra `border-collapse: collapse` à sua tabela (classe `rwd-table`). Veja essa [explicação no MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse).

Segue o código postado por você já com a regra definida:

```css
.rwd-table {
  margin: 1em 0;
  min-width: 300px;
  border-collapse: collapse /* Alteração */
}
.rwd-table tr {
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.rwd-table tr:first-child {
  border-top: none /* para não exibir uma linha antes da tabela */
}

.rwd-table tr:last-child {
  border-bottom: none /* para não exibir uma linha depois da tabela */
}

.rwd-table th {
  display: none;
}
.rwd-table td {
  display: block;
}
.rwd-table td:first-child {
  padding-top: .5em;
}
.rwd-table td:last-child {
  padding-bottom: .5em;
}
.rwd-table td:before {
  content: attr(data-th) ": ";
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 6.5em;
  display: inline-block;
}
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .rwd-table td:before {
    display: none;
  }
}
.rwd-table th, .rwd-table td {
  text-align: left;
}
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .rwd-table th, .rwd-table td {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: .25em .5em;
  }
  .rwd-table th:first-child, .rwd-table td:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  .rwd-table th:last-child, .rwd-table td:last-child {
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}

h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  color: #34495E;
}

.rwd-table {
  background: #34495E;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: .4em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.rwd-table tr {
  border-color: #46627f;
}
.rwd-table th, .rwd-table td {
  margin: .5em 1em;
}
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .rwd-table th, .rwd-table td {
    padding: 1em !important;
  }
}
.rwd-table th, .rwd-table td:before {
  color: #dd5;
}
```

```html
<style class="cp-pen-styles">@import "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,700";
.rwd-table {
  margin: 1em 0;
  min-width: 300px;
}
.rwd-table tr {
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.rwd-table th {
  display: none;
}
.rwd-table td {
  display: block;
}
.rwd-table td:first-child {
  padding-top: .5em;
}
.rwd-table td:last-child {
  padding-bottom: .5em;
}
.rwd-table td:before {
  content: attr(data-th) ": ";
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 6.5em;
  display: inline-block;
}
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .rwd-table td:before {
    display: none;
  }
}
.rwd-table th, .rwd-table td {
  text-align: left;
}
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .rwd-table th, .rwd-table td {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: .25em .5em;
  }
  .rwd-table th:first-child, .rwd-table td:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  .rwd-table th:last-child, .rwd-table td:last-child {
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}

h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  color: #34495E;
}

.rwd-table {
  background: #34495E;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: .4em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.rwd-table tr {
  border-color: #46627f;
}
.rwd-table th, .rwd-table td {
  margin: .5em 1em;
}
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .rwd-table th, .rwd-table td {
    padding: 1em !important;
  }
}
.rwd-table th, .rwd-table td:before {
  color: #dd5;
}
</style></head><body>
<h1>RWD List to Table</h1>
<table class="rwd-table">
  <tr>
    <th>Movie Title</th>
    <th>Genre</th>
    <th>Year</th>
    <th>Gross</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-th="Movie Title">Star Wars</td>
    <td data-th="Genre">Adventure, Sci-fi</td>
    <td data-th="Year">1977</td>
    <td data-th="Gross">$460,935,665</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-th="Movie Title">Howard The Duck</td>
    <td data-th="Genre">"Comedy"</td>
    <td data-th="Year">1986</td>
    <td data-th="Gross">$16,295,774</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-th="Movie Title">American Graffiti</td>
    <td data-th="Genre">Comedy, Drama</td>
    <td data-th="Year">1973</td>
    <td data-th="Gross">$115,000,000</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```